# Hidden message in pictures 1 (medium-hard)

Tags: visual, rebus

Trying something new here.

The following is the first of a set of hidden messages from a story.

Find the hidden sentence in this set of images. The order is from left to right and then from the first row to the second row.

[image]

For full size image, right-click the image → open in new tab.

**Hint 1**

> [image]

**Hint 2**

> Each grouped image from first hint represents one word from the sentence → The sentence has **6 words**.

**Hint 3**

> If you see an image of a box, just place the word "box" in the sentence. Repeat for all images. See what you get, or could possibly get.

**Hints for every image**

1

> There is a reason why the phone is iPhone and not other.

2

> What other word / verb can you get from a clock / time?

3

> The big arrow wants to show something... or somewhere.

4

> What does that number represents.

5

> Forget the cat.

6

> What word do those **2 different** pumpkins give you?

7

> It is not rainbow. Maybe reading these 2 words out loud will help.

Comment: [2,3] is it just a fish or any particular kind? i haven't seen a fish like that.

Comment: @SrinivasRa looks like a rainbow trout to me.

Comment: "iPhones tend to be in browsery pumpkin fishbubble." obviously.

Comment: Yes, that fish is the one.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You're on the right track, maybe not the right words.

Comment: More hints were added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll take a crack at it:

> **I am in very big trouble**

Explanation:

> iPhone -> I
>  Clock -> a.m.
>  Arrow going in box -> In
>  Version -> Ver. + Why -> Y = Very
>  Big pumpkin vs. small -> Big
>  Trout & Bubble smashed together sound like -> Trouble

I'm not sure what story this sentence is a part of, but it's natural and seems to fit the clues.

Comment: Well done, get ready for the next question :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will give it a shot, maybe i got some words right or help other people to think

> Call the time box and ask if it is headed to the pumpkin rainbow

Explanation:

> Picture of the phone = could be phone or call, it is at the begining so could be the verb call. Clock = time, not making much sense right now. Box = Box, I am a little lost. Header = that is a header. Cat = could imply a question. Pumpkin = pumpkin. Fish and bubble = Is a rainbow trout as Ian said in the comments, and the bubble makes a rainbow effect

Comment: Nope, check hint 2 again

Comment: Hah, none of your arguments is correct :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my version:

> I am in very nearby trouble

Based on Walt's version, but interpreting pumpkins as nearby or far off.

Comment: Since one pumpkin is much bigger than the other, that's what the image intended to say.